Fail to write Database and folder in Directus
I'm trying to setup Directus correctly and having issues with the database file and uploads folder. I can't write to both of them. The setup is pretty straight forward, fresh installed server, Docker on Ubuntu, running as root. I first created the folder localhost and run the docker there, it works without issues. Copied the folder to the server as the Directus documentation suggested.
This is the docker-compose file:
version: "3"
services:
directus:
image: directus/directus:latest
ports:
  - 8055:8055
volumes:
  - ./database:/directus/database
  - ./uploads:/directus/uploads
  - ./extensions:/directus/extensions
environment:
  SECRET: "itsasecret"
  ADMIN_EMAIL: "user"
  ADMIN_PASSWORD: "passw"
  DB_CLIENT: "sqlite3"
  DB_FILENAME: "/directus/database/data.db"
  WEBSOCKETS_ENABLED: "true"

The admin is reachable but once I'm trying to login, it gives a readonly failure:
Error: update `directus_sessions` set `next_token` =
'j8t5_CoKeRR7wCF5dc4k10uraO36fOFLuUzWGe31I64GqH2_SIFL1KYX0u_n5Nsm',
`expires` = '2024-06-26 10:17:36.856' where `token` =
'eOfOA0DTJyQT7c3LkkAT5VApa7UDOjDhFaWVWjw1vzmCKplvAfc_iBZF7FHbdtJE' and
`next_token` is null returning `next_token` - SQLITE_READONLY: attempt
to write a readonly database

I tried to change permission of database folder to 777 which worked (just to test) but once I upload a file, it gives a similar issue;
directus-1  | [23:28:26.805] WARN: EACCES: permission denied, open '/directus/uploads/e7a8bd40-3e7d-4fd2-aeff-aa45598f967f.png'
directus-1  |     err: {
directus-1  |       "type": "Error",
directus-1  |       "message": "EACCES: permission denied, open '/directus/uploads/e7a8bd40-3e7d-4fd2-aeff-aa45598f967f.png'",
directus-1  |       "stack":
directus-1  |           Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/directus/uploads/e7a8bd40-3e7d-4fd2-aeff-aa45598f967f.png'
directus-1  |       "errno": -13,
directus-1  |       "code": "EACCES",
directus-1  |       "syscall": "open",
directus-1  |       "path": "/directus/uploads/e7a8bd40-3e7d-4fd2-aeff-aa45598f967f.png"
directus-1  |     }

It seems to me as a permisssion/user problem. I've added to root user to the docker group
(sudo groupadd docker ,sudo usermod -aG docker $USER):
grep 'docker' /etc/group 
docker:x:987:root

I've also tried to level up the permissions to 755 for both database/upload folder. None of it worked, still the same issues.
What am I doing wrong?
